Why in AWS S3 bucket permissions Block public access through ACLs is active with disabled ACLs
If you go to AWS S3 bucket Permissions settings.
In the Object ownership section  you can set ACLs to the be disabled, it's said that:
"All objects in this bucket are owned by this account. Access to this bucket and its objects is specified using only policies.".
Doing so, the ACL section is disabled and the bucket owner has full access to objects while all other have none.
In the Block public access section you then have option to block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs) and through any access control lists (ACLs).
If ACL are disabled, why in the Block public access section choiches about ACL are still active?
To give public access to GET an object from its URL, in addition to set a bucket policy, in the Block public access section it's enough to unflag just the 4th choice (any policy) , but you don't have to unflag ACL choices.
So block if ACL flags are set but they don't seem to block public access. Does this choice effect some other behaviour?

Note that there's almost no need to use ACLs with S3 any more. Treat them as a legacy access control mechanism unless you have very specific needs not supported via BPA and S3 bucket policies.

Access Controls Lists (ACLs) are legacy access controls and are best avoided. In fact, the current recommendation is to disable ACLs on buckets and totally ignore them.
The ability to Block Public Access actually pre-dates the ability to disable ACLs, hence the confusion. If the ACLs are disabled, then the Block Public Access settings for ACLs are irrelevant.
